# Perl `split` does not `split` to default array

Tags: perl, split

I have this strange problem with `split` in that it does not by default `split` into the default array.

Below is some toy code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$A="A:B:C:D";
split (":",$A);
print $_[0];
```

This does not print anything. However if I explicitly split into the default array like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$A="A:B:C:D";
@_=split (":",$A);
print $_[0];
```

It's correctly prints A. My perl version is v5.22.1.

Comment: `@_` is not "the default array". `@_` is the array that contains parameters to a subroutine. There is nothing in the Perl documentation that calls it the default array.

Comment: @DaveCross that's not entirely correct. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARG says _Inside a subroutine, @_ is the default array for the array operators pop and shift_. But you are right of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) does not go to `@_` by default. `@_` does not work like `$_`. It's only for arguments to a function. [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARG) says:

> Within a subroutine the array @_ contains the parameters passed to that subroutine. Inside a subroutine, @_ is the default array for the array operators pop and shift.

If you run your program with `use strict` and `use warnings` you'll see

> Useless use of split in void context at

However, `split` does use `$_` as its second argument (the string that is split up) if nothing is supplied. But you must always use the return value  for something.

Comment: `split` in void context used to populate `@_`

Comment: @ikegami when was that?

Comment: Gone in 5.12. Deprecated at least as early as 5.8.8

Comment: @ikegami thanks for looking that up. I think we can leave that as a comment. OP is aking for 5.22. If you feel it should go into the answer, feel free to edit it in though.

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign the split to an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "A:B:C:D";
my @array = split(/:/, $string);
print $array[0] . "\n";
```

Comment: And don't call your variables `$a` `@a` - it's bad to use single letter names anyway, but especially when it is `$a` or `$b` which are used by `sort`