# Splitting a String with Perl

Tags: string, perl, split

I was following along with this [tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=591988) on how to split strings when I came across a quote that confused me.

> Words about Context
>
> Put to its normal use, split is used in list context. It may also be
>   used in scalar context, though its use in scalar context is
>   deprecated. In scalar context, split returns the number of fields
>   found, and splits into the @_ array. It's easy to see why that might
>   not be desirable, and thus, why using split in scalar context is
>   frowned upon.

I have the following script that I've been working with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.24;

doWork();

sub doWork {
    my $str = "This,is,data";
    my @splitData = split(/,/, $str);
    say $splitData[1];
    return; 
}
```

I don't fully understand how you would use split on a list.

From my understanding, using the `split` function on my `$str` variable is frowned upon? How then would I go about splitting a string with the comma as the delimiter?

Comment: @toolic - I could but it was from 2006, and I'll have to wait awhile until I get an answer. Here, I waited no more than 13 mins :D

Comment: The `@_` behavior was removed in 5.12 and deprecated in 5.8.8 - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153498/1331451

Comment: Your major confusion seems to be about what "context" is in Perl. Context is determined by what you do with the result of your expression (i.e. where the output goes), not where the input comes from. Of course, you should always give `split()` a scalar to work on. Whether the call is in scalar or list context is determined by whether the results are stored in an array (or list) or in a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frowned-upon behaviour documented by that passage was deprecated at least as far back as 5.8.8 (11 years ago) and was removed from Perl in 5.12 (7 years ago).

The passage documents that

```
my $n = split(...);
```

is equivalent to

```
my $n = do { @_ = split(...); @_ };            # <5.12
```

The assignment to `@_` is unexpected. This type of behaviour is called "surprising action at a distance", and it can result in malfunctioning code. As such, before 5.12, using `split` in scalar context was frowned-upon. Since 5.12, however,

```
my $n = split(...);
```

is equivalent to

```
my $n = do { my @anon = split(...); @anon };   # ≥5.12
```

The surprising behaviour having been removed, it's no longer frowned-upon to use `split` in scalar context for the reason stated in the passage you quoted.

It should probably still be avoided, not just for backwards compatibility, but because there are far better ways of counting the number of substrings. I would use the following:

```
my $n = 1 + tr/,//;    # Faster than: my $n = split(/,/, $_, -1);
```

---

You are using `split` in list context, so it does not exercise the frowned-upon behaviour, no matter what version of Perl you use. In other words, your usage is fine.

It's fine unless you are trying to handle CSV data, that is. In that case, you should be using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS).

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ auto_diag => 2, binary => 1 });

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { ... }   # Parsing CSV

for (...) { $csv->say($fh, $row); }            # Generating CSV
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm not using CSV data just yet(although, I know what that is). I'm still learning Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `split` in scalar context isn't very useful. It effectively returns the number of separators plus one, and there are better ways of doing that.

For example,

```
my $str = "This,is,data";
my $splitData = split(/,/, $str);
say $splitData;
```

will print `3` as it counts the substrings after the split.

`split` in scalarf context used to also return the split parts in `@_`, but that frowned-upon behaviour was removed because it's rather unexpected.

Using it as an array is perfect.

```
my $str = "This,is,data";
```

the above line is a single string.

```
my @splitData = split(/,/, $str);
```

You are now splitting the `$str` into an array, or a list of values. So effectively you are now sitting with @splitData which is in fact:

```
"This" "is" "string"
```

So you can either use them all, `say @splitData` or use each of them as a scalar `@splitData[1]` which we never use as it is always better to write it as `$splitData[1]`

The tutorial says it nicely. Use split on a string to create a list of substrings.

You can then obviously automatically assign each of the list values in a loop without having to print each list value.

```
my $str = "This,is,data";
my @splitData = split(/,/, $str);
foreach $value(@splitData) {
               say "$value\n"
 }
```

This basically re-assigns `$splitData[0], $splitData[1]` etc... to `$value` as scalar.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. There is nothing wrong with my script, correct?  I've been using split in the proper context?