# How to Convert Perl Map function to Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I want to convert a piece of perl code to python but I am not that familiar with perl at all and its syntax.

In particular, I am just confused about the map operator in perl, and the shift operator in the code below.

```
(@M) = ($y =~ m/((?:\d+:ITEM7 \d+:\d+ )+(?:\d+:ITEM7A \d+:\d+ )*)(?:\d+:ITEM8 \d+:\d+\s*)+/g);

$best = 0;
$bestseq = "";
for($i = 0; $i < scalar(@M); ++$i) {
  $m = $M[$i];
  $m =~ s/\d+://g;
  (@m) = (split / /, $m);
  $v = 0;
  $z = length_in_words($M[$i]);
  map { $v += $_ if($_ =~ m/^\d+$/); } @m;
  if($v > $best) { $best = $v; $bestseq = $M[$i]; }
}

sub length_in_words {
  my $x = shift;
  my @k;
  return scalar(@k = $x =~ m/(\S+)/sg);
}
```

I know that `@M` assigns an array based on the python `re.findall`, but I'm just confused about the map function, and the shift operator with how its applied to the `@k`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Pufff, that is scary :/

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, and asking us for a complete rewrite to Python probably makes your question too broad.

Comment: The `map` function is used for its side effect on incrementing `$v`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you've got a full explanation by ysth I can't help it but to rewrite that

A simple example

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw(sum0);    

my $y = ...    
my @M = $y =~ /.../;

my ($best, $bestseq) = (0, '');

foreach my $m (@M) {
    (my $new_m = $m) =~ s/\d+://g;
    my @w = split ' ', $new_m;         # CHANGED from original
    my $v = sum0 grep { /^\d+$/ } @w; 
    if ($v > $best) { 
        $best = $v; 
        $bestseq = $new_m; 
    }
}
    
sub length_in_words {
    return scalar split ' ', $_[0];
}
```

The loop appears to do the following.  Each element of `@M` array is pruned of `\d+:` (consecutive digits followed by `:`) and then split into words. All words which are numbers only are summed up.  This is used to find the largest ("best") such sum and to record its element.

Some comments

- A `foreach` *aliases* array elements in processing, so if operations change the currently processed element then the array changes as well.

  The original code does not change elements of `@M` so I first copy `$m` into a `$new_m` and work with that.  If this doesn't matter and `@M` may get changed in this loop, just do `$m =~ s/\d+://g;`, and use `$m` instead of `$new_m` elsewhere.
- index `$i` isn't used so iterate over array elements directly
- `$z` isn't used, removed
- that `map` sums up a filtered (only digits) subset of elements of `@m`
- original "best" initializes to zero thus use `sum0`, which gives zero with empty list input
- original `split / /, $m` splits the scalar `$m` by a *single* whitespace. I strongly suspect that the intention is to parse `$m` into words, so split by all consecutive whitespace.  Thus I use

  ```
    my @w = split ' ', $new_m;
  ```

  where `' '` is a special pattern that splits by any amount of whitespace, and drops leading and trailing spaces as well.  See [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). I renamed it to `@w` since it's clearly words.

One more comment: I'd use `@words`, `$val` (or such) rather than one-letter names.

---

A comment on code used in `length_in_words()` and efficiency.

There are various ways to count the number of words in a string, of course.  The benchmark below shows the one chosen here to be fastest

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Benchmark 'cmpthese';
    
my $run_for = shift // 3;  # seconds for each

my $text = " ah\n no \t hi  end ";

sub split_scalar {
   return scalar split ' ', $_[0];
}  

sub regex_context {
    my $wc =()= $_[0] =~ /\S+/g;
}   

sub regex_while {
    my $wc; 
    ++$wc while $_[0] =~ /\S+/g;
    return $wc; 
}   
        
cmpthese (-$run_for, {
    split_scalar  => sub { split_scalar($text) },
    regex_context => sub { regex_context($text) },
    regex_while   => sub { regex_while($text) },
});
```

Under v5.24.4 on a decent desktop this prints

```
                    Rate regex_context regex_while  split_scalar  
regex_context  1119833/s            --         -7%          -90%
regex_while    1203020/s            7%          --          -89%
split_scalar  11351365/s          914%        844%            --
```

For one, such a huge advantage of using `split` in scalar context is surprising to me and I'd guess it to be due to specific optimizations in `split`, from which this use case benefits.

Even more interestingly, when splitting a string  with 10_000 words the scalar-split way is even far more superior -- it gets to *4026 %*.

In my tests this showed consistent results in repeated runs on that desktop and on a server, with v5.16.3 and v5.24.4, with the following slight differences under the older Perl.

With v5.16 the advantage of `split` was a little lesser (still a factor of 7 though), and the play on context with `=()=` in regex wasn't any better than assigning to an array and returning `scalar` of it (in v5.24 it is, by 30-40%, so I left out the case that generates an array variable).

However, note that prior to v5.12 the `split` in scalar context had [surprising (nasty) behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44189818/4653379). Given the code in the question it is possible that this ran (runs?) on an older Perl (what doesn't excuse the shown code), in which case please use a regex based alternative instead `split`.

Thanks to [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) for comments.

Comment: Beware: `split` in scalar context has a nasty side effect in older perls.

Comment: That should be `sum0`, not `sum`, to perfectly replicate the original.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you, fixed and added comment.  Also added a benchmark, where `split`'s performance surprises.

Answer (score 4):

map is usually used to transform one list into another; here it is being abused to simply loop over `@m`.

The code is equivalent to:

```
for my $maybe_number (@m) {
    if ($maybe_number =~ /^\d+$/) {
        $v += $maybe_number;
    }
}
```

summing up all the elements of `@m` that are just one or more digits.

`my $x = shift;` inside a sub assigns the first argument to the sub to `$x`.

The last line of length in words finds all sequences of non-whitespace characters and assigns them to `@k`.  That assignment is placed in scalar context, which returns the number of elements assigned.  So it is counting how many "words" (sequences of non-whitespace characters) there are in the sub's argument.

Comment: Thank you. So just to clarify `@m` is an array that has been split on the white space of `$m` (as given by `(split / / @m)`, Then `maybe_number` iterates over each of those elements in `@m`. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes, that is correct